# is there any way to solve for x is $(e^x)/x =y$?

Tags: logarithms

I have tried using all the functions I know of and have been unable to get anywhere. I know it is impossible to solve this equation using elementary operations. I know it is impossible to solve for x with elementary functions because if $y=4$ there are two values of x. I tried using logarithms and got $x-ln(x)=ln(y).$ I am still stuck, what should I do?

Comment: I do not know, what your question is, since you gave a partial answer yourself.
You can not solve this equation in terms of 'regular' functions.

You can only solve it numericaly with a numerical method, such as Newtons Method, or you use the Lambert-W-function.

Comment: @Cornman could you please tell me how to solve this with the Lambert W function because I do not know how.

Comment: This is somewhat similar (not same):https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-equations-with-Ln-x-in-a-side-and-xs-on-the-other-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general $y$ there's no way to express $x$ using elementary functions. In general you need to use the special function called [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

You have $$ e^x/x  =y $$
$$ x e^{-x} = 1/y$$
$$ -x e^{-x} = -1/y$$
$$ -x = W(-1/ y)$$
$$ x=-W(-1/y)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac{e^x}{x}$$
then we can say:
$$xe^{-x}=\frac 1y$$
by letting $u=-x$ we get:
$$ue^u=-\frac 1y$$
Now we apply the Lambert W function to both sides:
$$u=W\left(-\frac 1y\right)$$
now undo the substitution:
$$x=-W\left(-\frac 1y\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newton's approximation method, by iteration.  In this particular case where $$y=\frac{e^x}{x}$$ the iteration will be: $$x_{n+1}=x_{n}-(x_{n}-e^x/Y)/(1-e^x/Y)$$ with $Y$ being the $y$ value for which we are trying to solve $x$.  The 'seed' value is $x_{1}$.  The iteration converges rapidly to both solutions of $x$ when $Y$=4.  For instance, for a seed value of $x_{1}=3$, $x$ converges to 2.15329236 (8 decimal places) in only 5 iterations.  For a seed value of $x_{1}=0.5$, $x$ converges to 0.357402956. The seed value interval must be so that the derivative of $$x-(x-e^x/Y)/(1-e^x/Y)$$ be $\le m <1$.  I have not checked out the details but it appears that this is true for a wide range of positive or negative $x$ values.